# How do I make a keyboard shortcut for Terminal in CentOS 7

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, centos7

Just installed CentOS 7 on my laptop. This new version of CentOS is pretty different from older ones, and I cannot make  a keyboard shortcut for Terminal in older ways.
Dose anybody know how ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Go to Settings >>> keyboard >>> Shortcuts tab >>> Custom Shortcuts >>> click "+"
Name: Terminal Shortcut
Command: gnome-terminal
Now a new shortcut added with status "disabled". Click on "disabled" word and assign your shortcut. 
For me, I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to run Terminal

Comment: By default, the shortcut shown to me was `Alt`+`Tab`.  By clicked on it, to change it to `New Accelerator`, then I pressed `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` to update the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I wonder what the feature designer was thinking when they chose the word "Disabled" for something which doesn't have a key combination assigned yet, and why couldn't the first screen where you define the command take the key combination as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I chose 'Super' + t where 'Super' is the Windows key on the keyboard.

Comment: For anyone confused how to access 'settings'.
Move cursor ALL THE WAY to the upper left hand of screen. You'll see a seach box pop up at the upper middle; then type keyboard in it.

Answer (score 10):

On Gnome 3 GUI you may follow these 16 steps,

1. Click `Activities` on the top left

[image]

---

2. Click `Show Applications` on the bottom left

[image]

---

3. Click `Settings` icon at the top middle

[image]

---

4. Click `Keyboard` icon in the middle of `All Settings`

[image]

---

5. Scroll down the v-scroll bar until `Custom Shortcuts` section appears
6. Then, click `+` icon

[image]

---

7. Enter `Terminal Shortcut` in `Name` text box.
8. Enter `gnome-terminal` in `Command` text box.
9. Click `Add` button

[image]

---

10. In the `Custom Shortcuts` section, ‘disabled’ shortcut will appear
11. Click the word `Disabled`

[image]

---

12. Click `Edit` button next to `Shortcut None`

[image]

---

13. All grey popup will be shown
14. Type a shortcut(eg, Shift+Ctrl+M)

[image]

---

15. Close window by pressing `X` mark on top right

[image]

---

16. Shortcut(s) you just defined will be shown as follows

[image]

---

That's it. Try pressing the shortcut and you will have the Terminal Opened with the home directory.

Comment: How do you make a shortcut like this print out a unicode character? I can't seem to make it work with `echo ñ`